# IIB Prefix to a field

Tags: xml, soap, ibm-integration-bus

I´m using the IIB 10.0.0.11

When I call my SOAP service with this message:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="urn://hfgroup.co.ke/SharedResources/Schemas/SOAMessages/SoapHeader" xmlns:com="urn://hfgroup.co.ke/Common/DataModel/Common/SecureGetBusinessDate/1.0/Common.SecureGetBusinessDate" xmlns:ns="urn://hfgroup.co.ke/CanonicalDataModel/Security/1.0">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <soap:HeaderRequest>
         <soap:Control>
            <soap:RequesterSystemCode>013</soap:RequesterSystemCode>
            <soap:MessageID>45</soap:MessageID>
         </soap:Control>
         <soap:Credentials>
            <soap:Credential>
               <soap:Username>ESBAPP01</soap:Username>
               <soap:Password>!@#$_!K@O#C$E%L^A*_$#@!</soap:Password>
            </soap:Credential>
         </soap:Credentials>
      </soap:HeaderRequest>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <com:DataInput>
         <com:SecureGetBusinessDateInput>
            <ns:Security>
               <ns:ChannelId>99997</ns:ChannelId>
            </ns:Security>
         </com:SecureGetBusinessDateInput>
      </com:DataInput>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

everything work as it should but when I received this message:

```
<NS1:Envelope xmlns:NS1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  >
   <NS1:Header>
      <NS2:HeaderRequest xmlns:NS2="urn://hfgroup.co.ke/SharedResources/Schemas/SOAMessages/SoapHeader">
         <NS2:Control>
            <NS2:RequesterSystemCode>013</NS2:RequesterSystemCode>
            <NS2:MessageID>49</NS2:MessageID>
         </NS2:Control>
         <NS2:Credentials>
            <NS2:Credential>
               <NS2:Username>ESBAPP01</NS2:Username>
               <NS2:Password>!@#$_!K@O#C$E%L^A*_$#@!</NS2:Password>
            </NS2:Credential>
         </NS2:Credentials>
      </NS2:HeaderRequest>
   </NS1:Header>
   <NS1:Body>
      <NS3:DataInput xmlns:NS3="urn://hfgroup.co.ke/Common/DataModel/Common/SecureGetBusinessDate/1.0/Common.SecureGetBusinessDate">
         <NS3:SecureGetBusinessDateInput>
            <NS4:Security xmlns:NS4="urn://hfgroup.co.ke/CanonicalDataModel/Security/1.0">
               <NS4:ChannelId>99997</NS4:ChannelId>
            </NS4:Security>
         </NS3:SecureGetBusinessDateInput>
      </NS3:DataInput>
   </NS1:Body>
</NS1:Envelope>
```

The IIB turn the prefix NS3 and NS4 as a field and i will errors later in the service:

the tree variables in debug:

```
SOAP
    Context
           Namespace
                    NS1:CHARACTER:http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/

Body
    DataInput
            NS3:CHARACTER:urn://hfgroup.co.ke/Common/DataModel/Common/SecureGetBusinessDate/1.0/Common.SecureGetBusinessDate
            SecureGetBusinessDateInput
                    Security
                            NS4:CHARACTER:urn://hfgroup.co.ke/CanonicalDataModel/Security/1.0
                            ChannelId:CHARACTER:99997
```

how I can resolve this issue for not having the prefix as a field?

the log of what is sending to the service:

```
0x03000102:NamespaceDecl):xmlns                                           = 'urn://hfgroup.co.ke/Common/DataModel/Common/GetBusinessDate/1.0/Common.GetBusinessDate' (CHARACTER)
      (0x03000102:NamespaceDecl)xmlns:nsS100                                     = 'urn://hfgroup.co.ke/CanonicalDataModel/Security/1.0' (CHARACTER)
      (0x03000102:NamespaceDecl)xmlns:soapenv                                    = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' (CHARACTER)
      (0x01000000:Folder       )http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/:Body   = (
        (0x01000000:Folder)urn://hfgroup.co.ke/Common/DataModel/Common/GetBusinessDate/1.0/Common.GetBusinessDate:DataInput = (
          (0x01000000:Folder)urn://hfgroup.co.ke/Common/DataModel/Common/GetBusinessDate/1.0/Common.GetBusinessDate:GetBusinessDateInput = (
            (0x01000000:Folder)urn://hfgroup.co.ke/CanonicalDataModel/Security/1.0:Security = (
              (0x03000000:PCDataField)http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/:NS4                              = 'urn://hfgroup.co.ke/CanonicalDataModel/Security/1.0' (CHARACTER)
              (0x03000000:PCDataField)urn://hfgroup.co.ke/CanonicalDataModel/Security/1.0:ChannelId = '99997' (CHARACTER)
              (0x03000000:PCDataField)urn://hfgroup.co.ke/CanonicalDataModel/Security/1.0:CoreToken = 'Z]XWVUTSr>P<NW>Mw;MZ' (CHARACTER)
            )
          )
        )
```

Comment: It is normal that the debugger shows the namespaces as fields. Can you please share the errors you receive later in the service?

Comment: The security structure is later copied to a equal structure to call another service. The service that is called has the error: problem creating SOAP tree from bitstream. and Text:CHARACTER:An XML parsing error has occurred while parsing the XML document        
Text:CHARACTER:The namespace prefix "xmlns" was not declared.
Text:CHARACTER:/XMLNSC/{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}:Envelope/{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}:

Comment: Can you please show us the code that you use to create the SOAP message tree?

Comment: Cont: Body/{urn://hfgroup.co.ke/Common/DataModel/Common/GetBusinessDate/1.0/Common.GetBusinessDate}:DataInput/{urn://hfgroup.co.ke/Common/DataModel/Common/GetBusinessDate/1.0/Common.GetBusinessDate}:GetBusinessDateInput/{urn://hfgroup.co.ke/CanonicalDataModel/Security/1.0}:Security

If i take the NS4 to the root of the original message it works

Comment: SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.ns250:Envelope.ns250:Body.nszF00:DataInput.nszF00:GetBusinessDateInput.nsS100:Security = Environment.XMLNSCRequest.*:DataInput.*:SecureGetBusinessDateInput.*:Security;
and 
DECLARE ns250 NAMESPACE 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
DECLARE nszF00 NAMESPACE 'urn://hfgroup.co.ke/Common/DataModel/Common/GetBusinessDate/1.0/Common.GetBusinessDate';
DECLARE nsS100 NAMESPACE 'urn://hfgroup.co.ke/CanonicalDataModel/Security/1.0';

Comment: It is easier to read if you add this additional info to the question and not comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see in your comments that you did not declare the SOAP namespace correctly: It misses the leading `http://`. Please try it like this:

```
DECLARE ns250 NAMESPACE 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
DECLARE nszF00 NAMESPACE 'urn://hfgroup.co.ke/Common/DataModel/Common/GetBusinessDate/1.0/Common.GetBusinessDate';
DECLARE nsS100 NAMESPACE 'urn://hfgroup.co.ke/CanonicalDataModel/Security/1.0';
SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.ns250:Envelope.(XMLNSC.NamespaceDecl)xmlns = nszF00;
SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.ns250:Envelope.(XMLNSC.NamespaceDecl)xmlns:nsS100 = nsS100;
SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.ns250:Envelope.(XMLNSC.NamespaceDecl)xmlns:soapenv = ns250;
```

And I see as well from your comments and the trace output that you copy data from the `Environment`; the `PCDataField` field in the trace tells me that there is no domain information in the `Environment` (see [similiar problem](http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB/viewtopic.php?t=51130)). Here a quote from the [InfoCenter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.scenarios.doc/gop_03/topics/bj60052_.htm)

> Copying a message tree (or a portion of it) into the Environment can be useful for many scenarios, but it is essential that the correct domain is created prior to copying the structure. Forgetting to assign the correct domain to the Environment tree before copying the fragment of the input message causes inflation of the tree to occur before the copy happens

So please copy your input data like this to the `Environment`:

```
CREATE LASTCHILD OF Environment DOMAIN 'XMLNSC' FROM InputRoot.XMLNSC;
```

Comment: Did not work.
when i the message with the : <NS4:Security xmlns:NS4="urn://hfgroup.co.ke/CanonicalDataModel/Security/1.0"> in the original message it only work when I map field by field. If I map the structure like I showed it not work.

Comment: Please insert a trace node to your flow and post the relevant output. Make sure you format this as code so the indentation is not lost.

Comment: Just edit my post with the log with the message that is send to the service

Comment: It work perfectly. thank you very much. never see a so hard tool to work as IBM.

Comment: Well, it took me a while to get used to as well, but you will see its elegance after you climbed the learning curve...